# react frontend connecting to flask backend Howto

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, flask-restful

I have a ReactJS front end and a flask backend and I am having difficulties making both talk to each other, particular sending form variables from the frontend to Flask.

Given below is my front end code which runs on 127.0.0.1:3000

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Form1 extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
        <div class="form">
            <form action="/result" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="place" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
<Form1/>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My backend flask code is as given below and runs on 127.0.0.1:5000

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'GET':
      result = request.form
      print (result['place'])
```

Comment: If you're serving the react page on one port, but trying to access a service on another port, then you'd need to specify that somewhere - probably `<form action="127.0.0.1:5000/result" method="get">`

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: changing to `<form action="127.0.0.1:5000/result"` returns an `about:blank` page.

Comment: First problem: your flask method `def result()` does not return anything to the client. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#routing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have tweaked your code a little bit.
Changes I have made:

- added the backend path `http://localhost:5000/result` in frontend as form action path.
- used `request.args.get` method to grab the submitted value.

The frontend is running on port 3000 and the backend is running on port 5000; both in `localhost`.

Frontend code:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Form1 extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div class="form">
                <form action="http://localhost:5000/result" method="get">
                    Place: <input type="text" name="place"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Form1/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Backend Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/result', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        place = request.args.get('place', None)
        if place:
            return place
        return "No place information is given"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Here is the screenshot of running program:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Flask documentation: The request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object)