# Flask: how to render React component instead of server response

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have a similar application as the problem described here: [react frontend connecting to flask backend Howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777708/react-frontend-connecting-to-flask-backend-howto)

The solution works for me; however, the solution renders the result using the server response rather than passing the information back to the frontend React. You can see in the solution, the output is using the localhost:5000 port whereas I'd like to keep the response in localhost:3000 (i.e. keep it within the React component). Can someone help me better understand how i can pass data from React (i.e. a text input) -> Flask (some manipulation) -> back to React (result is rendered in the React component).

I haven't been able to find a tutorial that really covers the need I have here. If you could point me to one, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?